# For loops over character strings

Tags: r, for-loop, character, rendering

I have a data set with a Locations column and other columns.

```
Locations <- c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", ..."Test60")
```

I also have several Rmd files.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "[.]Rmd$")
```

Each Rmd file does different things and each result spits out a csv file. Let's say I have 3 Rmd files. I need to run these Rmd files for each Location in Locations. (So I should have 180 csv files)

I am trying to write a for loop so that every location in Locations runs through the 3 Rmd files. 
The code looks like this:

```
for (location in Locations){
  for (f in files){
    rmarkdown::render(f) 
    write.csv(results, paste(f, location, ".csv", sep=''))
  }
}
```

This does result in 180 csv files, but they are exactly the same. (all 180 csv files are results based off of 'Test1'.

I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: What's `results`?

Comment: the output of the 3 Rmd files.

Comment: Msybe show the command to create it. Don't you think that's the key here?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your file name with the `paste` function, you're doing the following: Let's assume your first file is called `file1.Rmd`, then you are saving your first set of results to `file1.RmdTest1.csv` - so whilst that is not fatal, it is a bit weird.

Secondly, your call to `rmarkdown::render` doesn't actually depend on the value of `location`, so there is no reason for the results to be different in each iteration of the inner loop. Maybe you want to load some results before `for(f in files)` ?